# Highlight or bold font for entire row that contain current date in a cell

Tags: wordpress

There is 1 table at my wordpress page to show our job proggress status. This table generally generated from csv file then plugin will convert to html. I would like to highlight or bold font for entire row that contain current date in a cell. So that users can easily check today's status. This table at my wordpress page.

HTML

```
<table class="csvtohtml">
      <thead>
        <tr class="headers">
          <th class="colset colset-1">LASTEST UPDATE: 27/Sep/2019 17:49 </th>
          <th class="colset colset-2"> </th>
          <th class="colset colset-3"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="rowset odd rowset-1">
          <td class="colset colset-1">STATION NUMBER</td>
          <td class="colset colset-2">DATE </td>
          <td class="colset colset-3">TAG</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowset even rowset-8">
          <td class="colset colset-1"> Station1 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-2"> 25/09/2019 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-3">409</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowset odd rowset-9">
          <td class="colset colset-1"> Station1 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-2"> 26/09/2019 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-3">464</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowset even rowset-10">
          <td class="colset colset-1"> Station1 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-2"> 27/09/2019 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-3">364</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowset odd rowset-11">
          <td class="colset colset-1"> Station2 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-2"> 25/09/2019 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-3">428</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowset even rowset-12">
          <td class="colset colset-1"> Station2 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-2"> 26/09/2019 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-3">370</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowset odd rowset-13">
          <td class="colset colset-1"> Station2 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-2"> 27/09/2019 </td>
          <td class="colset colset-3">142</td>
        </tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lbhq8nje/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css highlight first row

```
.rowset.odd.rowset-1:first-child { color: red; font-weight: bold;}
```